# calling a method having parameters context and attributeset from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, custom-view

I have an app that displays random characters vertically on the screen (like in the matrix movie) and I would like to add buttons to change the color of these chars when pressed, but I'm unable to call the method `setColor` of `paintTxt` variable from `MainActivity`.

This is my code,

```
EffetMatrix effetMatrix = new EffetMatrix();//Error in ()
final Paint paintTxt = effetMatrix.paintTxt;
paintTxt.setColor(Color.RED);
```

But the editor shows an error:

> EffetMatrix(Context, AttributSet) in EffetMatrix cannot be applied to ()

the EffetMatrix class code

package com.esqmo.apps.effetmatrix;

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;    

/**
 * Created by esQmo on 04/10/2016.
 */
public class EffetMatrix extends View {
    private static final Random ALEATOIRE = new Random();
    private int larg, haut;
    private Canvas toile;
    private Bitmap toileBmp;
    private int taillePolice = 40;
    private int tailleColonne;
    private char[] chars = "01".toCharArray();
    private int[] posTxtParColonne;
    public Paint peindreTxt, peindreArrPlan, peindreArrPlanBmp, peindreInitArrPlan;

    public EffetMatrix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        peindreTxt = new Paint();
        peindreTxt.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        peindreTxt.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        peindreTxt.setTextSize(taillePolice);

        peindreArrPlan = new Paint();
        peindreArrPlan.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        peindreArrPlan.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        peindreArrPlan.setAlpha(5);

        peindreArrPlanBmp = new Paint();
        peindreArrPlanBmp.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        peindreInitArrPlan = new Paint();
        peindreInitArrPlan.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        peindreInitArrPlan.setAlpha(255);
        peindreInitArrPlan.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int l, int h, int ancl, int anch) {
        super.onSizeChanged(l, h, ancl, anch);

        larg = l;
        haut = h;

        toileBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(larg, haut, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        toile = new Canvas(toileBmp);
        toile.drawRect(0, 0, larg, haut, peindreInitArrPlan);
        tailleColonne = larg / taillePolice;

        posTxtParColonne = new int[tailleColonne + 1];

        for (int x = 0; x < tailleColonne; x++) {
            posTxtParColonne[x] = ALEATOIRE.nextInt(larg / 2) + 1;
        }

    }

    private void dessineTexte() {
        for (int i = 0; i < posTxtParColonne.length; i++) {
            toile.drawText("" + chars[ALEATOIRE.nextInt(chars.length)], i * taillePolice,
                    posTxtParColonne[i] * taillePolice, peindreTxt);
            if (posTxtParColonne[i] * taillePolice > larg && Math.random() > 0.980) {
                posTxtParColonne[i] = 0;
            }
            posTxtParColonne[i]++;
        }
    }

    private void dessineToile() {
        toile.drawRect(0, 0, larg, haut, peindreArrPlan);
        dessineTexte();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas toile) {
        super.onDraw(toile);
        toile.drawBitmap(toileBmp, 0, 0, peindreArrPlanBmp);
        dessineToile();
        invalidate();
    }
    public void setCustomColor(int color){
        peindreTxt.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }


}
```

note: variable peindreText = paintText

The main activity code:

```
package com.esqmo.apps.effetmatrix;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.effect.Effect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button boutton_vert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_v);
        final Button boutton_bleu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_b);
        final Button boutton_rouge = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_r);
        final Button boutton_rose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_ro);

        boutton_bleu.setOnClickListener(this);
        boutton_vert.setOnClickListener(this);
        boutton_rouge.setOnClickListener(this);
        boutton_rose.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    public void passerVert(View v) {

    }

    public void passerRouge(View v) {

    }

    public void passerRose(View v) {

    }

    public void passerBleu(View v) {


    }
}
```

main.xml

> ```
> <com.esqmo.apps.effetmatrix.EffetMatrix
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:id="@+id/arrPlan"/>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="50dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>     android:background="#040404"
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="70dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:text="@string/button_vert"
>         android:onClick="passerVert"
>         android:id="@+id/b_v"
>         android:textAppearance="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="70dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:text="@string/button_bleu"
>         android:onClick="passerBleu"
>         android:id="@+id/b_b"/>
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="70dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:text="@string/button_rouge"
>         android:onClick="passerRouge"
>         android:id="@+id/b_r" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="70dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:text="@string/button_rouge"
>         android:onClick="passerRose"
>         android:id="@+id/b_ro" />
>
>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

PS: I'm a noob in programming.
Sorry for my english

Comment: Is `EffetMatrix` a custom view?

Comment: Unclear what `EffetMatrix` is, but what parameters are you confused about?

Comment: You're going to have to show us your implementation for `EffectMatrix` in order for us to debug this.

Comment: yes it is @K Neeraj Lal

Comment: EffetMatrix is the custom view, it has context and attributeSet as parameters

Comment: Do you have it in the xml already? Also, can you edit the `EffetMatrix` class or is it precompiled?

Comment: yes, <com.esqmo.apps.effetmatrix.EffetMatrix
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/arrPlan"/>

Comment: I can edit EffetMatrix class

Comment: @Chris Gong, i have edited

Comment: @esQmo is the CustomView actually showing when you're running the app?

Comment: yes, everything works but I've added 4 buttons each one for a specific color. only the default color _paintTxt.setColor(Color.BLUE);_

Comment: @esQmo What are the buttons called? I don't see them in your question.

Comment: @esQmo and are the buttons part of the custom view? I'd suggest editing your question to reflect any changes you've made to the code

Comment: no @Chris Gong, please check my edited post. with full code

Comment: @esQmo alright see my answer with regards to your issue about the buttons not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new instance of the custom view again. Instead get a reference to the view using its id.

See the following code,

```
EffetMatrix effetMatrix = (EffetMatrix) findViewById(R.id.arrPlan);
effetMatrix.setCustomTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Inside `EffetMatrix` class create a method named `setCustomColor` as follows,

```
class EffetMatrix {
    ...

    public void setCustomTextColor(int color){
        // Set the color to the paintTxt object
        paintTxt.setColor(color);
        // invalidate the view to apply the changes
        invalidate();
    }

    ...
}
```

This is how you implement it in your code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {
    EffetMatrix effetMatrix;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        effetMatrix = (EffetMatrix) findViewById(R.id.arrPlan);        
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.b_b:
                effetMatrix.setCustomTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case R.id.b_r:
                effetMatrix.setCustomTextColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case R.id.b_ro:
                effetMatrix.setCustomTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must invalidate your custom view after changing paint color.

```
effetMatrix.invalidate();
```

And if you want to display your custom view in editor you must implement :

```
public EffetMatrix(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public EffetMatrix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);  
}
```

Comment: the app run normally on my phone, but i wanted to add buttons that i can change the color of the characters. eg when i clik on the button for blue; all characters turns blue...

Comment: @esQmo ok, just call invalidate() method after changing paint color. `effetMatrix.invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the buttons do something, then you have to set an `onClickListener` for each button in your main properly. Here's an example for `button_bleu`,

Get rid of `boutton_bleu.setOnClickListener(this);` and replace it with

```
button_bleu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
         effetMatrix.setCustomColor(Color.BLUE);
      }
    });
```

Now just do the same for the other 3 buttons.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but effetMatrix.setCustomTextColor(Color.blue); returns cannot resolve symbol 'effetMatrix'

Comment: @esQmo did you mispell "effectMatrix"? I believe you spelled it "effetMatrix" without the "c"

Comment: effectMatrix or effetMatrix ? i thought you mispelled it

Comment: @esQmo my mistake you are right, it is "effetMatrix" and I edited my answer to fit your method, "setCustomColor"

Comment: ok, but cannot resolve symbol still here. I don't know where I am wrong... setCustomTextColor is defined in EffetMatrix class

Comment: @esQmo ah but see it's not, you called it "setCustomColor" instead of "setCustomTextColor" in the `effetMatrix` class, so it should be "setCustomColor" in the main

Comment: @esQmo unless you changed something in your `effetMatrix` class then that's how it should be.

Comment: solved. i mispelled setCustomTextColor in EffetMatrix class. now it works

Comment: @esQmo Alright glad I could help. If you found the answer useful then don't forget to upvote or accept the answer. Good luck coding!

Comment: @esQmo it's the checkmark right below my answer's score on the upper left